# Best way to build REST api for a search with operands JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm trying to build a REST api for my application. The basics are done. But now I need some help to for a search with different parameters and their operands.

Let's say I have a JSON String like this:

```
{"v00Datvon":"09-07-2014","v00Datbis":"09-07-2014","v00Saicode":{"saiCode":"SO02"}}
```

These are values of my "contract" domain object.

For the search at the UI part, you can choose for the two dates an operand (greater or less or equals)

All the parameters (without the operands) are sent per GET and Ajax call.

The Spring MVC Controller looks like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getContractsFromSearch(@RequestParam String allRequestParams, ModelMap model){
    //some stuff
    }
```

I'm looking for technical input, how to add the operands to the JSON String and Controller in a clean and good way. I dont want to hack some bad code. 
If you need more input, please leave a comment.
Thanks!

**Update 1.**

GET Request:

```
allRequestParams={"v00Datvon":"09-07-2014","v00Datbis":"09-07-2014","v00Saicode":{"saiCode":"SO02"}}
```

**Update 2.**

```
    {
  "dateFrom": {
    "dateFrom": "someDate",
    "operand": "less"
  },
  "dateTo": {
    "dateTo": "someDate",
    "operand": "greater"
  },
  "season": {
    "season": "someSeason",
    "operand": "equals"
  }
}
```

**Update 3**
Deserialization:

```
public static Contract fromJsonToContract(String json) {
    return new JSONDeserializer<Contract>().use(Calendar.class, new CalendarTransformer("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")).use(null, Contract.class).deserialize(json);
}
```

Comment: Could you please show us an example for a `GET` request? How do the parameters look like in the URL?

Comment: At the moment I do not add the operands into the parameters. I'm not sure to do it in a good way.

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: Use ISO-8601 encoding for dates. The `GET` URL looks find.

Comment: The GET Url is working fine. That isnt the problem. I need some help to add the parameters of operands to this Url. In a clean and good way. May be there will be some standards? Thanks

Comment: What about `&operand=greater` or `&operand=equal` or `&operand=less`?

Comment: Yes that will be the way. But I stock more at the JSOn part and after building the object. How should the JSON looks like in "update 2" at the question?

Answer (score 0):

First of all as per your Controller how you passing Map as requestParam,That can't possibile,Have you try this

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getContractsFromSearch(HttpServletRequest request, Object> allRequestParams, ModelMap model){
Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
while(paramNames.hasMoreElements())
{
      String paramName =
(String)paramNames.nextElement();
      out.print(paramName);
}
    //some stuff
    }
```

Comment: The map is working fine. The output of the map looks like this: `{dateFrom=02-07-2014, dateTo=02-07-2014, season=SO03}` But do you have some suggestions for adding the operands to the parameter list with your solution?

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: before moving to your controller put some filter logic where you can easily append operands

Comment: ok. But how should the json look like? Like in update 2 in question? Or is there any standard?

Comment: yes you can prefer update2 json that's look meaningful

Comment: Ok. But the parsing of JSON string to contract object will not work after adding operands. Do you have some ideas to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I think your JSON is too verbose: you have an entry named "dateFrom" that has an entry named "dateFrom", try to keep it simple and "flat". What about this option?:

```
 {
  "dateFrom": "someDate",
  "operandFrom": "less",

  "dateTo": "someDate",
  "operandTo": "greater",

  "season": "someSeason",
  "operandSeason": "equals"

}
```

I know that group data by semantic is tempting, but in a GET request you have to think the best way to process the parameters.The data can be easily transformed to:

```
dateFrom=someDate&operandFrom=less&dateTo=someDate&operandTo=greater&season=someSeason&operandSeason=equals
```

or just send one parameter with the JSON as value:

```
q={"dateFrom": "someDate","operandFrom":"less","dateTo":"someDate","operandTo":"greater","season":"someSeason","operandSeason":"equals"}
```

But then you'd need to parse it in your controller.