# How to get JSON String with Subdomain in Java Map at Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, javascript, json, rest, spring-mvc

I'm trying to receive a JSON String with subdomain to a Java Map at Spring MVC Controller.

Let's say I have this JSON at the JavaScript part:

```
var contract = {dateFrom:someDate,
           dateTo:someDate, 
           season: {seasonCode:someString}}
```

The JSON is sent as GET Ajax call.

The Controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> getVertagFromSearch(@RequestParam Map<String, Object> allRequestParams, ModelMap model){
```

The output of the Map looks like this:

```
{dateFrom=02-07-2014, dateTo=02-07-2014, season[seasonCode]=SO03}
```

The GET Request looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/contracts/?dateFrom=02-07-2014&dateTo=02-07-2014&season%5BseasonCode%5D=SO03
```

I want to parse this Map into my contract domain object. But with this structure it doesnt work. Without a subdomain(season) it worked.

Thanks in advance!

**Update 1**

Sending as an object it looks like this: (output Browser)

```
Object { dateFrom: "09-07-2014", dateTo: "08-07-2014", season: Object }
```

Sending after JSON.stringify it looks like this:

```
"{"fromDate":"09-07-2014","dateTo":"08-07-2014","season":{"saiCode":"SO03"}}"
```

In this case I think the probem are the double quotes at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: Are you sure the JS object is sent as a valid JSON structure?, I mean, with all keys within double quotes and so on. A lot of people forget that `(JS object) != JSON`

Comment: @Pablo Yes your right. See my update. I got the problem with double quotes. In second case its clear, the map gets only the key not a value. Because its one String

Comment: What is the GET request now? As you are sending a JSON in the URI, there must be a "name" for that parameter.

Comment: With stringify the request is `http://localhost:8080/contracts/?{%22dateFrom%22:%2209-07-2014%22,%22dateTo%22:%2208-07-2014%22,%22season%22:{%22saiCode%22:%22SO03%22}}` . What do you mean with "name"?

Comment: Yes sure. Stupid question. Now I have in the map the `key=contract` and `value=<jsonString>`.  And vaule will be parsed to vertrag object. This works.  Thanks

Comment: If the answer suits you, please mark it as selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best two options are:

**1) Modify your JS object to have only simple objects**. If you look at your request URL before your update, you had:

> {your IP:port}/contracts/?dateFrom=02-07-2014&dateTo=02-07-2014&season%5BseasonCode%5D=SO03

That is not JSON at all, is a simple request with three parameters:

```
 dateFrom = 02-07-2014 
 dateTo = 02-07-2014
 season%5BseasonCode%5D= SO03   // %5B and %5D are '[' and ']' escaped
```

So your javascript is transforming a JS object (not JSON) in plain parameters.

**2) Send a parameter, a string, with your JSON structure** and then use some JSON library to parse it:

```
http://localhost:8080/contracts/?myJson=<JSON_String>
```

and then modify your controller as:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=text/plain")
public ResponseEntity<String> getVertagFromSearch(@RequestParam String myJson, ModelMap model){
    JSONObject myJSON= new JSONObject (myJson);
    ...
}
```

Usually sending a JSON is easier with a POST (just adding it to the body), but as your request seems to ask for data, a POST request is not a good idea. Most of the rest APIs use the first approach, JSON tends to be part of a response more than part of a GET request.

Comment: Thanks, the second part will be the way I think. Based on this question I got another question regarding adding operands. Maybe you have also a solution for that. [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547767/best-way-to-build-rest-api-for-a-search-with-operands-json/24549205?noredirect=1#comment38061285_24549205)