# cannot map ajax json data to spring controller's object parameter

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I made a ajax post call in the front end.

```
let data = {
        marketplaceId: "1",
        monetaryAmount: {
            amount: 100,
            currencyCode: "USD",
        }, 
    }

    $.post(posturl, data, function(returnedData) {
            console.log(returnedData)
        }
       ).fail(function() {
           console.log("error")
       })
```

In my spring mvc controller, I want to map monetaryAmount json object to A java object SimpleAmount.

SimpleAmount.java

```
public class SimpleAmount {
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private String currencyCode;


  public BigDecimal getAmount() {
    return this.amount;
  }

  public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
  }


  public String getCurrencyCode() {
    return this.currencyCode;
  }

  public void setCurrencyCode(String currencyCode) {
    this.currencyCode = currencyCode;
  }
}
```

Controller.java

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/rpl/updateasinlimit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public BGCServiceResponseStatus updateAsinLimit(
            @RequestParam Long marketplaceId,
            @RequestParam @RequestBody SimpleAmount monetaryAmount) {

        ......
    }
}
```

**However, `SimpleAmount monetaryAmount` never gets mapped properly. It seems to me that all those primitive type will get mapped easily, but not java object**

**But I dont know how I can map json object sent from ajax post to the parameter passed into spring controller?**

Answer (score 0):

Your request body is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`(not json) and looks like:

```
marketplaceId=1&monetaryAmount%5Bamount%5D=100&monetaryAmount%5BcurrencyCode%5D=USD
```

---

**Problem 1** is that when we use application/x-www-form-urlencoded, Spring doesn't understand it as a RequestBody. So, if we want to use this we must remove the @RequestBody annotation. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38252958/1032167)

---

**Problem 2**
Spring actually has hard time understanding the percent encoding format ( %5D and %5B) for some reason.

---

Here is how you can solve this: [Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24571370/1032167), [Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22649971/1032167).

One more option is to create response POJO

```
public class SomeResponse {
    private long marketplaceId;
    private SimpleAmount monetaryAmount;

}
```

Change you js code to actually send `json` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/rpl/updateasinlimit",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(data) { alert('data: ' + data); },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

And then you can use it like this in controller:

```
public String updateAsinLimit(
        @RequestBody SomeResponse pojo) {
        System.out.println(pojo.getMarketplaceId());
        System.out.println(pojo.getMonetaryAmount());

        // ...
}
```